# CRUD operations with EntityFramework using generic type

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics

I want to be able to use a generic service class of type T that will allow me to query the database dynamically. For example. Normally i would do something like this to delete a record

```
public void Delete(Post post)
{
    this._context.Posts.Remove(post);
}
```

I want to be able to do this

```
public void Delete(T post)
{
    this._context<T>.Remove(post);
}
```

I found an article here that sort of brushes over it, but if doesnt seem like a clean way to implement it. https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2013/05/30/generic-dal-using-entity-framework/

Comment: Just use `_context.Set<T>().Remove(post)`

Comment: In the net you can find many articles regarding generic repository implementation with EF such as [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/814768/CRUD-Operations-Using-the-Generic-Repository-Patte) or [this](https://cpratt.co/truly-generic-repository/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need `DbContext.Set`

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679544(v=vs.113).aspx

> Returns a non-generic DbSet instance for access to entities of the given type in the context and the underlying store

```
public void Delete<T>(T post)
    where T : class
{
    this._context.Set<T>.Remove(post);
}
```

For later on, you can also query based on:

```
this._context.Set<T>.AsQueryable().Where(predicate);
```

In this instance `predicate` would be a `Expression<Func<T, bool>>`

So you can have a generic query method:

```
public IEnumerable<T> Query<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
    where T : class
{
    return this._context.Set<T>().AsQueryable().Where(predicate).ToList();
}
```

... but I'm digressing from the question slightly now!

Comment: Tried this, but i get an error. The type 'T' must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter 'TEntity' in the generic type or method 'DbContext.Set<TEntity>()'

Comment: ah- see my update for `Query` - you need the where clause

Answer (score 1):

You can use Generic repository pattern

```
public class Repository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    private dynamic _context;
    private DbSet<TEntity> _dbSet;

    protected DbContext Context
    {
        get
        {
            if (_context == null)
            {
                _context = DataContextFactory.GetDataContext();
            }

            return _context;
        }
    }

    protected DbSet<TEntity> DBSet
    {
        get
        {
            if (_dbSet == null)
            {
                _dbSet = this.Context.Set<TEntity>();
            }

            return _dbSet;
        }
    }

    public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> Find(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate, Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderExpression = null)
    {
        return this.GetQuery(predicate, orderExpression).AsEnumerable();
    }

    public virtual IQueryable<TEntity> GetQuery(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate = null, Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderExpression = null)
    {
        IQueryable<TEntity> qry = this.DBSet;

        if (predicate != null)
            qry = qry.Where(predicate);

        if (orderExpression != null)
            return orderExpression(qry);


        return qry;
    }

    public virtual void Insert<T>(T entity) where T : class
    {
        DbSet<T> dbSet = this.Context.Set<T>();
        dbSet.Add(entity);
    }

    public virtual void Insert(TEntity entity)
    {
        this.DBSet.Add(entity);
    }

    public virtual void Update<T>(T entity) where T : class
    {
        DbSet<T> dbSet = this.Context.Set<T>();
        dbSet.Attach(entity);
        this.Context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }

    public virtual void Update(TEntity entity)
    {
        this.Attach(entity);
        this.Context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }

    public virtual void Delete<T>(T entity) where T : class
    {
        DbSet<T> dbSet = this.Context.Set<T>();

        if (this.Context.Entry(entity).State == EntityState.Detached)
            dbSet.Attach(entity);

        dbSet.Remove(entity);

    }

    public virtual void Delete(TEntity entity)
    {
        if (this.Context.Entry(entity).State == EntityState.Detached)
            this.Attach(entity);

        this.DBSet.Remove(entity);

    }

    public virtual void Delete<T>(object[] id) where T : class
    {
        DbSet<T> dbSet = this.Context.Set<T>();
        T entity = dbSet.Find(id);
        dbSet.Attach(entity);
        dbSet.Remove(entity);

    }

    public virtual void Delete(object id)
    {
        TEntity entity = this.DBSet.Find(id);
        this.Delete(entity);
    }


    public virtual void Attach(TEntity entity)
    {
        if (this.Context.Entry(entity).State == EntityState.Detached)
            this.DBSet.Attach(entity);
    }

    public virtual void SaveChanges()
    {
        this.Context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
public class Sample
{
    public void AddNewPerson(Person newPerson)
    {
        var personRepo = new Repository<Person>();
        personRepo.Insert(newPerson);
        personRepo.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void DeletePerson(int personId)
    {
        var personRepo = new Repository<Person>();
        Person person= personRepo.Find(p => p.Id == personId).SingleOrDefault();
        personRepo.Delete(person);
    }
}
```

Comment: Will this work if `Person` has hierarchy of child objects like `List<Address>`?